# Is there any difference in meaning between "He had not replied to me until yesterday" and "He still had not replied..." here?

Tags: sentence-meaning, comparison

1. He had not replied to me until yesterday.
2. He still had not replied to me until yesterday.

What is the difference between the two sentences in their meaning?

In my own understanding, the first sentence means that he had replied to me yesterday. But for the second one, I think it means that he didn't reply to me yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

They *both* say he replied, but I can't think of a context where either sentence would be needed.

The sequence might go like this:

> On Monday he hadn't replied to me and on Tuesday he *still* hadn't replied.
> He didn't reply until yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, both sentence here has the same meaning, with or without the "still".
However, still can be used to emphasize.

You can check this [link](https://www.crownacademyenglish.com/meaning-use-still-english/) to see the usage of "still"

Answer (score 0):

Both mean that "*he had replied to me yesterday*".

The second with "still" is different in that it emphasizes time.

> We use “still” to indicate and emphasise that something is continuing.
> A situation has NOT finished, perhaps surprisingly.
>
> Example:
>
> (Monday): Mark: How are you feeling? Jane: I have a cold.
>
> (Tuesday): Mark: How are you feeling today? Jane: I still have a cold.

https://www.crownacademyenglish.com/meaning-use-still-english/

Someone might use 2 instead 1 to mean that "*he replied to me yesterday which took more time than expected*".